# sorting matrix in R when column name is string

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix with 300 columns, where rows correspond to gene counts and columns correspond to sample name. 
R order columns in following format:

```
sample59 sample6 sample60 sample61 sample62 sample63 sample64 sample65
[1,]  2       679.567      361        2       17        0        0        0
[2,]  0       0.000        0        0        0        0        0        0
[3,]  0       0.000        0        0        0        0        0        0
[4,]  0       0.000        0        0        0        0        0        0
[5,]  0       0.000    0        0        0        0        0        0
[6,]  0       0.000    0        0        0        0        0        0
```

I would like to format matrix like this:

```
sample6 sample59 sample60 sample61 sample62 sample63 sample64 sample65
[1,]  679.567       2      361        2       17        0        0        0
[2,]    0.000       0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[3,]    0.000       0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[4,]    0.000       0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[5,]    0.000       0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[6,]    0.000       0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

How I can reorder the whole matrix?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's read in your column names.

```
cnames <- scan(what = "character", text ="
sample59 sample6 sample60 sample61 sample62 sample63 sample64 sample65")
```

Now let's solve the column order problem, with some fake matrix.

```
library(stringr)

mat <- matrix(1:80, ncol = 8)
colnames(mat) <- cnames

icol <- str_order(colnames(mat), numeric = TRUE)
mat2 <- mat[, icol]
mat2
```

Comment: Thank you! 
That works perfectly on the whole dataset.

Answer (score 2):

```
# get column names of your dataframe (called df) and remove the "sample" word
n = sub("sample", "", names(df));
# and convert n to numbers (as they are, right?)
n = as.numeric(n)

# reorder your data.frame column depending on the n sorting
df = df[, order(n)];
```